# Passing Selected Row in Data Table to Another State in Spring Web-Flow

Tags: jsf, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I can not manage to solve this with my limited Spring_flow knowledge. Here is my two view-states.

```
    <view-state id="viewPatientState" view="viewPatient.xhtml" model="patient">
    <transition on="newPatient" to="addPatient" />
    <transition on="viewPatient" to="viewPatientState" />
    <transition on="viewPatientProfile" to="patientProfile">

    </transition>

</view-state>

<view-state id="patientProfile" view="patientProfile.xhtml" model="patient">
    <transition on="newPatient" to="addPatient" />
    <transition on="viewPatient" to="viewPatientState" />

</view-state>
```

I want to send patient object or just an id(integer) to patientProfile from viewPatient.Here is my viewPatient.xhtml. I just want to pass the selected row's id or selected object.

```
<p:dataTable id="tbl" var="pat"
            value="#{patientService.getAllPatients()}" paginator="true"
            rows="10">

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Hasta No" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{pat.patientId}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column exportable="false">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Soyisim" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{pat.lastName}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="İsim" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{pat.firstName}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column exportable="false">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Yaş" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{pat.age}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column exportable="false">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Profil" />
                    </f:facet>
                </f:facet>
                <p:commandLink id="profileLink" action="viewPatientProfile"
                    ajax="false">
                    <h:outputText value="Detay" />
                </p:commandLink>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using "patient" as model in your view state definition. Just add one field in Patient class say selectedPatientId and refer that in the view.
I believe your "patient" model is in flowscope. If it is in flowscope, it will retain the user selection. when you navigate from view "viewPatientState" to view "patientProfile".

```
    public class Patient implements Serializable{
        public String selectedPatientId;
        ...
        //setters and getters
    }
```

You can find more details about scoped variables [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.x/reference/html/el.html#el-variable-flowScope).